# Подгон содержимого загружаемой в WebView страницы под размер экрана

Tags: javascript, java, html, android, dom

Общая информация:

- есть сайт без мобильной вёрстки, предназначен для онлайн-отчётности и потому гораздо удобнее было бы иметь подстройку под ширину экрана;
- разрабатываемое "приложение" имеет одну activity на которую navigation drawer вызывает фрагменты с webview, каждый фраг представляет определённый раздел сайта;
- поскольку используется загрузка страницы в overviewMode, некоторые страницы подстраиваются под размер самостоятельно, но есть страницы (например с таблицами), которые не влезают по ширине;
- использую javasript-ы, чтобы модифицировать страницы и пока лучшего решения не нашёл (моска маловато)...

Теперь, собственно суть вопроса:

1. Поскольку пишу на java и javasript-ом подгребаю, решил динамически менять содержимое страницы, можно ли в `<head>` вставить тэг `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">` до того, как начнёт грузиться `<body>`?
2. Можно ли через саму webView (не используя js и webView.setInitialScale) выполнить подгон содержимого под экран?
3. Как можно обернуть всё это в asincTask или что-то похожее, чтобы загрузка страницы и скриптов происходила в background-e?? (тупо делать webview невидимой и потом снова видимой не помогает, всё равно на доли секунды появляется сама страница, а потом уже подгружаются скрипты);
4. И, напоследок...может я вообще всё неправильно делаю и можно было проще? Есть идеи?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ordo_ereticus.ttk_agent2;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import fragments.FourthScreen;
import fragments.ScreenEight;
import fragments.ScreenFive;
import fragments.ScreenNine;
import fragments.ScreenOne;
import fragments.ScreenSeven;
import fragments.ScreenSix;
import fragments.ScreenTen;
import fragments.ScreenThree;
import fragments.ScreenTwo;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String[] mScreenTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mScreenTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mScreenTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ttk, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        // Initialize the first fragment when the application first loads.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }else {onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);}
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        if (mDrawerToggle != null)
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu;

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ScreenOne();

                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ScreenTwo();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ScreenThree();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new FourthScreen();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new ScreenFive();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new ScreenSix();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new ScreenSeven();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new ScreenEight();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new ScreenNine();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new ScreenTen();
                break;
            case 10:
                fragment = new ScreenOne();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mScreenTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // Error
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error. Fragment is not created");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

}
```

Один из фрагментов:

```
package fragments;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.ordo_ereticus.ttk_agent2.R;
public class ScreenFive extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_five, container, false);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView6);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://ttk-chita.ru/agent/balance-call");


        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);}});
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresh:
                Refresh();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                Logout();
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        mWebView.reload();
    }

    public void Logout() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://ttk-chita.ru/agent/logout");
    }
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mProgress.bringToFront();
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
            "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-default')[0].style.display = 'none';})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByTagName('H5')[0].style.display =" +
            " 'none';})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function()  {var x = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');" +
            "var i; for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {x[i].style.padding = '8px 0px';x[i].style." +
            "fontSize='12px';x[i].style.borderLeft='1px solid #dddddd';}})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function()  {var x = document.getElementsByTagName('TH');" +
            "var i; for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {x[i].style.padding = '8px 0px';x[i].style." +
            "fontSize='12px';x[i].style.borderLeft='1px solid #000000';x[i].style.border" +
            "Bottom='1px solid #000000';x[i].style.borderTop='1px solid #000000';}})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function()  {var x = document.getElementsByClassName('container');" +
            "var i; for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {x[i].style.padding = '0px';x[i].style." +
            "margin='0px';}})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var b= document.createElement('BUTTON'); document.body.appendChild(b); b.innerHTML='Alert'; b.onclick = function al(){alert('!!!');};})()");
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function met(){var me=document.createElement('META'); me.id='" +
            "viewport'; me.name='viewport'; me.content='width=device-width, user-scalable=yes';" +
            "var hd=document.head;var old=hd.getElementsByTagName" +
            "('meta'); old.remove(); document.body.insertBefore(me, document.body.firstChild);})()");
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Вопрос с метой отпал, т.к. в моём случае не работает даже если страница загружается не с сайта, а лежит в памяти и `<meta>` уже прописана...

Answer (score 5):

Всем заинтересовавшимся, большое спасибо! Решение оказалось до боли простым - вставка мета-тэга не в `<head>`, а в `<body>`.
Далее просто идёт использование одновременно `mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`
и
`mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`
плюс, подстройка размеров элементов для большей читабельности.
Надеюсь, кому-нибудь тоже поможет:
1. в метод `onCreateView` фрагмента вписываем:
`mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`
2. в методе `onLoadResource` или `onPageFinished` класса `WebViewClient` вставляем в тело страницы мета-тэг `viewport`:
`mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var m=document.createElement('META'); m.name='viewport'; m.content='width=device-width, user-scalable=yes'; document.body.appendChild(m);})()");`.
3. наслаждаемся результатом, либо допиливаем напильником элементы страницы, чтобы они были более читабельны (в моем случае, я просто поубирал лишние паддинги).